# alert($(document).html();)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html page with jquery enabled.

Once the user modifies the page with jquery interactions, I need to save the resulting DOM.

As per [Get Jquery DOM][1], $(document).html(); should give me the html so I am trying to alert the

```
$(document).html();
```

However I get the alert undefined element

http://jsfiddle.net/ujYzM/3/

Please can somebody help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need Followups buddy!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to get the DOM using `$('html')` or `$('body')`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/sYxpj/)

```
alert($('html').html());
alert($('body').html());
```

Comment: I used alert($('html').html());

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#sketch_board").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'smbrd',
        tollerance: "touch",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#sketch_board").append($('#div_drag').html());
            var x = $('#sketch_board').text();
            alert(x);
        }
    });

    $('#div_drag').draggable({
        containment: "window",
        revert: true
    });
});
```